# Black screen in Java after upgrading to PlayN 1.3.1

Tags: lwjgl, playn

I've been looking into this for a day or two now. I've found other people who have had similar problems in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/playn/OfkJjYxxaCc). According to the "Where to download" section of this [minecraft wiki](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Update_LWJGL) there is a known problem of black screens on 64-bit machines using LWJGL since v2.8.1. I've tried using older versions of LWJGL with no luck; I'd still get the black screen. Does anybody have a solution to get this working on a 64-bit machine?

Comment: Of course as soon as I decide to ask a question about it I found it that it was something I was doing wrong.

Comment: What were you doing wrong, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: When loading assets using an asset watcher it returns immediately on java. Problem was my main focus is on HTML which returns asynchronously so once I got it working on HTML I thought I was all set. Then I updated to 1.3.1 and then blamed the black screen on LWJGL. Turns out I had to load slightly differently based on the platform.

Comment: Oh. As far as I know, asset loading in the HTML platform has always been asynchronous, I remember having similar issues because of that. How unfortunate that it coincided with the 1.3.1 upgrade in your case.